# agrep in R - find *all* matches in a string (global flag)

Tags: r, agrep

I've got a string:

```
string <- "I do not like green eggs and ham!"
```

and a pattern

```
pattern <- "(egs|ham)"
```

**I want to know how many times `pattern` matches `string` with fuzzy matching (agrep)**.

`gregexpr` will do this for normal matching - I just want to know if there's a corresponding `garegexpr` in R or a way to emulate it without being too performance-heavy.

(`aregexec` will only return the index for the first match, "eggs", and skip "ham").

Comment: Did you figure out an answer?

Answer (score -1):

You didn't specify that you need base R, so I'll happily suggest using the str_count(string, pattern) function from the "stringr" package by Hadley Wickham.

```
library(stringr)
string <- "I do not like green eggs and ham!"
pattern <- "(egs|ham)"
str_count(string, pattern)
[1] 1
```

stringr really is a great R package. Full of all sorts of string usefulness.

Comment: That's great, but it isn't fuzzy matching. I'm after a similar function but using `agrep` instead of `grep` (I can already emulate `str_count` using `gregexpr`)